# How come no 'var' needed inside js function?

Tags: javascript

How come this works and returns `123` twice:

```
function hello(){
  hello123 = 123

  console.log(hello123)
}

hello()
console.log(hello123)
```

1. How come I don't need to declare the variable `hello123` with `var`
2. How come the variable persists outside the function? Is that because it's declared on window with the function being part of that scope?

Thanks

Comment: Try [`console.log(window.hello123)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Global_variables) as well.

Comment: Tip: Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).